# Test process.env with Jest

Tags: node.js, testing, environment-variables, jestjs

I have an application that depends on environmental variables like:

```js
const APP_PORT = process.env.APP_PORT || 8080;
```

And I would like to test that for example:

- APP_PORT can be set by a Node.js environment variable.
- or that an [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) application is running on the port set with `process.env.APP_PORT`

How can I achieve this with Jest? Can I set these `process.env` variables before each test or should I mock it somehow maybe?

Comment: yes you can set the environment variable

Comment: @Deep AFAIK I can set them only once in jest config.

Answer (score 424, accepted):

The way I did it [can be found in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042200/invalidate-node-cache-when-using-jest).

It is important to use [resetModules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestresetmodules) before each test and then dynamically import the module inside the test:

```
describe('environmental variables', () => {
  const OLD_ENV = process.env;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules() // Most important - it clears the cache
    process.env = { ...OLD_ENV }; // Make a copy
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    process.env = OLD_ENV; // Restore old environment
  });

  test('will receive process.env variables', () => {
    // Set the variables
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'dev';
    process.env.PROXY_PREFIX = '/new-prefix/';
    process.env.API_URL = 'https://new-api.com/';
    process.env.APP_PORT = '7080';
    process.env.USE_PROXY = 'false';

    const testedModule = require('../../config/env').default

    // ... actual testing
  });
});
```

If you look for a way to load environment values before running the Jest look for the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953365/4443323). You should use [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#setupfiles) for that.

Comment: Please provide the full response

Comment: Worked great for me. If you need to use a default export you can do: const testedModule = require('../../config/env').default;

Comment: in case this doesn't work for you, make sure when you are reading the env variable in your actual code, you are reading it in a function/limited scope rather than having a global variables pointed to process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE.

Comment: I'm not understanding why are you deleting variables beforeEach() and setting up afterEach(). The behavior should be inverse right, like setup variables beforeEach() test and delete afterEach()?

Comment: @learner if I remember correctly `delete process.env.NODE_ENV; ` is just a leftover from my code and shouldn't matter in your case. What matters is that you call `jest.resetModules()` before the test and after it you restore initial process.env object (OLD_ENV)

Comment: Isn't `process.env = { ...OLD_ENV }` and `process.env = OLD_ENV` the same thing? Why double syntax?

Comment: @MEMark you need to create a copy in order not to mutate the original object (which later you need to restore)

Comment: Don't forget, you will also have to re-wire any mocks that are dependent on being `require`'d... 
after you `resetModules` in your `beforeEach`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, no matter what I try

Answer (score 293):

Jest's [`setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#setupfiles) is the proper way to handle this, and you need not install `dotenv`, nor use an `.env` file at all, to make it work.

`jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/.jest/setEnvVars.js"]
};
```

`.jest/setEnvVars.js`:

```
process.env.MY_CUSTOM_TEST_ENV_VAR = 'foo'
```

That's it.

Comment: I tried most of the solutions proposed in this thread and this is the one that worked for me.

Comment: This is the best solution! For my production apps I'm using this to set global mocks too. For example if you're dealing with momentjs you can set the timezone here so your snapshots won't fail when changing timezone.

Comment: Amazing, that's the simplest option to handle environment variables in jest!

Comment: I'm not sure what people are happy about, as it clearly doesn't work for any real use case where `process.env` is read by modules at the import/require time.

Comment: This doesn't really work if you need to adjust environment variables on a per-test-case basis...

Comment: @jrista reaplce afterAll with afterEach

Comment: It's also deprecated now; so that is fun.

Answer (score 76):

Another option is to add it to the `jest.config.js` file after the `module.exports` definition:

```
process.env = Object.assign(process.env, {
  VAR_NAME: 'varValue',
  VAR_NAME_2: 'varValue2'
});
```

This way it's not necessary to define the environment variables in each `.spec` file and they can be adjusted globally.

Comment: This is a great solution for when you want to test different environment variables per test. Most of the other answers I've come across have been at a global level. Thanks!

Answer (score 53):

In `./package.json`:

```
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/jest/setEnvVars.js"
  ]
}
```

In `./jest/setEnvVars.js`:

```
process.env.SOME_VAR = 'value';
```

Comment: Probably the easiest way I've seen. No need to install the dotenv package.

Comment: this won't work with Create-React-App https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5325 for that, env variables to be used in test need to be added in .env.test.local file

Comment: This didnt work for me with vue-test-utils

Comment: This didnt work for me because, my env var needed to be initialized before the module loads. So I ended up splitting it in two separate files and define the var before loading the module and that worked. Not a pretty way but work.

Answer (score 42):

You can use the `setupFiles` feature of the Jest configuration. As [the documentation said](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) that,

> A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up
> the testing environment. **Each setupFile will be run once per test
> file.** Since every test runs in its own environment, these scripts will
> be executed in the testing environment immediately before executing
> the test code itself.

1. `npm install dotenv --save-dev` dotenv that uses to access environment variable.
2. Create your `.env` file to the root directory of your application and add this line into it:

   ```
   #.env
   APP_PORT=8080
   ```
3. Create your custom module file as its name being *someModuleForTest.js* and add this line into it:

   ```
   // someModuleForTest.js
   require("dotenv").config()
   ```
4. Update your `jest.config.js` file like this:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     setupFiles: ["./someModuleForTest"]
   }
   ```
5. You can access an environment variable within all test blocks.

   ```
   test("Some test name", () => {
     expect(process.env.APP_PORT).toBe("8080")
   })
   ```

Comment: Nice answer! This is a such a clean approach but instead use `npm install dotenv --save-dev ` since it doesn't need to be apart of you application. For simple projects I just skip step 4. and have step 3 at the top of my test file(s) instead of creating a custom module.

Answer (score 26):

Expanding a bit on [Serhan C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033841/test-process-env-with-jest/57944454#57944454)...

According to the blog post *[How to Setup dotenv with Jest Testing - In-depth Explanation](https://tekloon.dev/using-dotenv-with-jest)*, you can include `"dotenv/config"` directly in `setupFiles`, without having to create and reference an external script that calls `require("dotenv").config()`.

I.e., simply do

```
module.exports = {
    setupFiles: ["dotenv/config"]
}
```

Comment: Only this that runs in my side

Comment: The best solution here! It's worth mentioning, that in `jest.config.ts` you can use it under the `globalSetup` key instead of the `setupFiles` key, if you want it to run once before all tests, and not resetting them before every test file

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion, it's much cleaner and easier to understand if you extract the retrieval of environment variables into a utility (you probably want to include a check to fail fast if an environment variable is not set anyway), and then you can just mock the utility.

```
// util.js
exports.getEnv = (key) => {
    const value = process.env[key];
    if (value === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`Missing required environment variable ${key}`);
    }
    return value;
};

// app.test.js
const util = require('./util');
jest.mock('./util');

util.getEnv.mockImplementation(key => `fake-${key}`);

test('test', () => {...});
```

Comment: I feel like this is the only way to test check like: `isProd ? /*something*/ : /*something else*/`, for time when you want to send an email for example. Or when relying on external services that do not have a proper test env.

Answer (score 10):

In test file:

```
const APP_PORT = process.env.APP_PORT || 8080;
```

In the test script of `./package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "jest --setupFiles dotenv/config",
 }
```

In `./env`:

```
APP_PORT=8080
```

Comment: If you want to use a dotenv file with a name other than `.env`, e.g., `.env.test`, you can set it via env var: `DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=./.env.test jest --setupFiles dotenv/config`

Answer (score 6):

Depending on how you can organize your code, another option can be to put the environment variable within a function that's executed at runtime.

In this file, the environment variable is set at import time and requires dynamic `require`s in order to test different environment variables (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48042799/530653)):

```
const env = process.env.MY_ENV_VAR;

const envMessage = () => `MY_ENV_VAR is set to ${env}!`;

export default myModule;
```

In this file, the environment variable is set at `envMessage` execution time, and you should be able to mutate process.env directly in your tests:

```
const envMessage = () => {
  const env = process.env.MY_VAR;
  return `MY_ENV_VAR is set to ${env}!`;
}

export default myModule;
```

Jest test:

```
const vals = [
  'ONE',
  'TWO',
  'THREE',
];

vals.forEach((val) => {
  it(`Returns the correct string for each ${val} value`, () => {
    process.env.MY_VAR = val;

    expect(envMessage()).toEqual(...
```

Answer (score 5):

you can import this in your jest.config.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

this work for me

Answer (score 5):

To build upon @HenryTipantuña's suggestion is to import dotenv in your jest.config.js and use a .env.test file in the config path

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: '.env.test'
})
```

Comment: This worked for me plus
**module.exports = {setupFiles: ['dotenv/config']}**

Answer (score 4):

All the above methods work if you're using `require("dotenv").config` within the `jest.config.js` file, a NodeJS application without TypeScript such as what Jialx or Henry Tipantuna has suggested.

But if you're using **ts-jest** and within the **jest.config.ts** file.

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()

/* config options below */
```

Answer (score 4):

When using Typescript the following works for me:

in root:
jest.config.js

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');

const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig.paths.json');

module.exports = {
  // [...]
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' }),
};
process.env = Object.assign(process.env, {
  env_name: 'dev',
  another_var: 'abc123',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of @jahller's answer.

I made it responsive so you don't need to keep the files in sync as things change.

Put this at the bottom of your `jest.config.js` file.

```
const arr = require('fs')
  .readFileSync('.env', 'utf8')
  .split('\n')
  .reduce((vars, i) => {
    const [variable, value] = i.split('=')
    vars[variable] = value
    return vars
  }, {})

process.env = Object.assign(process.env, arr)
```

It reads the contents of your .env file, splits every new line and reduces it all back down to an object where you then assign it to `process.env`

**OR**

just use dotenv in `jest.setup.js` ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

i have most simple for implementation env (specialy test.env)

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: './test.env' });
const { sum } = require('./sum.js');

describe('sum', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules(); // remove cache
  })

  test('should success', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 3)).toEqual(4);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this too:

```
const currentEnv = process.env;
process.env = { ENV_NODE: 'whatever' };

// test code...

process.env = currentEnv;
```

This works for me and you don't need module things

Comment: the problem is that if you import another file that uses process.env then changing it directly won't take any effect. So before each test, you need to tell Jest something like - "hey import and execute this file again".

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for `NodeJS` (18) and `Typescript` (tested with 4 and 5) that uses `dotenv-flow` npm package:

Install `dotenv-flow` package:

```
npm i dotenv-flow
```

> or use pnpm, yarn

Create a jest setup file (e.g. src/setupJest.ts)

```
import * as dotenvFlow from 'dotenv-flow'
dotenvFlow.config()
```

Modify the jest.config.ts file:

```
import type { JestConfigWithTsJest } from 'ts-jest'

const config: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  ... <your existing configuration settings> ...
  setupFiles: ['./src/setupJest.ts']
}

export default config
```

Then simply use `process.env.<YOUR_ENV_VAR>` in jest tests