# How to cover unit test of "if statement" in jest dependeing of external variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have the following Javscript code:

```
const authenticationTypeMapping = (payload) => {
  const { API_CONFIG } = process.env;

  try {
    const apiConfig = JSON.parse(API_CONFIG.toString('utf8'));
    // set authenticationType to Federated for production
    if (apiConfig.API_BASE_URL.includes('prd')) {
      payload.authenticationTypeName = 'Federated';
      // set authenticationType to Federated for dev or UAT
    } else if (apiConfig.API_BASE_URL.includes('dev') || apiConfig.API_BASE_URL.includes('uat')) {
      payload.authenticationTypeName = 'Basic';
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Failed to map authenticationType. Unable to parse Secret: ${err}`);
  }
  return payload;
};
```

I have problem to cover unit test using jesty for the code for the lines inside try block.

If statement depends on external variable "apiConfig.API_BASE_URL" of "process.env" which I don't how to represent to jest code.

```
it('should call authenticationTypeMapping', async () => {
    const payload = mapper.authenticationTypeMapping(basicPayload);
    expect(payload.authenticationTypeName).toEqual('Basic');
});
```

What should be added to cover the unit test?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test process.env with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033841/test-process-env-with-jest)

Comment: also some related info in [Invalidate node cache when using Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48042200/1318694)

Comment: @Matt what is content of const testedModule = require('../../config/env').default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Environment in the test and check for the same condition in the unit test as follows

```js
it('should call authenticationTypeMapping', async () => {
    process.env.API_BASE_URL = 'prd...'
expect(mapper.authenticationTypeMapping(basicPayload).authenticationTypeName).toEqual('Federated');
    process.env.API_BASE_URL = 'dev...'
expect(mapper.authenticationTypeMapping(basicPayload).authenticationTypeName).toEqual('Basic');
});
```

Maybe you can have more than one unit tests to make things clear like one to test 'prd' and one to test 'dev'

Comment: shouldn't be process.env.API_BASE_URL= 'prd...' instead of process.env.API_CONFIG = 'prd...' ??

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the mistake