# Jest is throwing error > Type Error : Cannot read property 'user_env_variable is undifined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

While testing the application with Jest I'm getting an `Type Error : Cannot read property 'user_env_variable is undefined` error.

[image]

because of `'user_env_variable is undefined'` error I have modified if else check

```
if(config.user_env_variable) {...} else {...}
```

to

```
if(config.user_env_variable!== undefined) {...} else {...}
```

but still I am getting the same error.

*This is how my dbconfig.json will look like*

**dbconfig.json**

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "dev",
    "password": "******",
    "database": "userdb",
    "host": "user-management-dev-xxxx",
    "port": "5432",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
}
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033841/test-process-env-with-jest this one?

Comment: Try  `typeof` operator. something like this `if(typeof config.user_env_variable!== "undefined") {...} else {...}`

Comment: @Sagar even after using `typeof` I'm still getting the same error

Comment: What are you using `"undefined"` as string or keyword?

Comment: I'm using Keyword

Comment: How do you call dbconfig.json?

Comment: `var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';`  `var config    = require(__dirname + '/../dbconfig/dbconfig.json')[env];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `typeof` operator. Something like this. Check `undefined` is string not keyword.

`if(typeof config !== "undefined" && typeof config.user_env_variable!== "undefined") {...} else {...}`

Comment: Can you please log your `config` object using `console.log(config)`. And check once it is `user_env_variable` or `use_env_variable`

Comment: I did that but there is no either `use_env_variable` or `user_env_variable` present

Comment: Then sure your `config` object is undefined. Above answer is updated. Please check.

Comment: great! your solution worked. But some new problems arised

Comment: `var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);` now in this code error is coming `config.database` is not defined. I noticed that `jest` test is giving error, but the value is displaying in dev run (nodemon).

Comment: Because your `config` object is not defined anywhere in the code. Get your `config` object right in the first place then your other problems will gone away or check everywhere `typeof config !== "undefined"` with appropriate `&&` or `||` condition.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found major mistake in my code which caused all these bugs.

Answer (score 0):

use This:

```
if(typeof(config.user_env_variable==="undefined"))
```

or use typeof undefined this is gonna solve your problem

Comment: Ok I understand
use this :
typeof(config.user_env_variable) === "undefined"