# How to set process.env to undefined in jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to unit test a function in my application that checks the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV`.  FWIW the type of `process.env.NODE_ENV` is `string | undefined`.

In my jest test, I can easily test string values when it's set like this:

```
it('test', () => {
  // Arrange
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

  // Act
  functionUnderTest();

  // Assert
  export(true).toBe(true);
});
```

The problem arises when I want to test my code's handling of `process.env.NODE_ENV` being set to `undefined`.  I would expect to be able to simply set `process.env.NODE_ENV = undefined` in my jest test.  Unfortunately, it would seem that somewhere along the line, the value is converted to a `string` such that when the test hits my function, the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` is `"undefined"` (as a string).

I've also tried to set `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `undefined` like this, but with the same result:

```
process.env = Object.assign(process.env, { NODE_ENV: undefined });
```

**How can I set `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `undefined` in a jest test?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test process.env with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033841/test-process-env-with-jest)

Answer (score 2):

Just `delete` the `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

E.g.

```js
function functionUnderTest() {
  return process.env.NODE_ENV;
}

describe('66787053', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
    const actual = functionUnderTest();
    expect(actual).toBe('development');
  });

  it('should pass', () => {
    delete process.env.NODE_ENV;
    const actual = functionUnderTest();
    expect(actual).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66787053/index.test.js (6.951 s)
  66787053
    ✓ test (2 ms)
    ✓ should pass

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.061 s
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me . In `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jest.env.js"
    ]
  }
```

and the `src/jest.env.js` looks like

```
process.env.REGION = 'us-west-2'
```