# Mock a const variable with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, segment

I have a file with a variable declared as const:

*sendFunction.js*

```
const Analytics = require('analytics-node');
const writeKey = process.env.WRITE_KEY;

//Call Segment service
export const sendAnalytics = () => {
   return new Analytics(writeKey).track({
        userId: clientKey,
        event: USER_EVENT,
        properties: {
            Action: userEvent,
            
        }
    });
}
```

I have a Jest unit test that is testing the function, and the function required the `writeKey` so that we can trigger the `sendAnalytics()` function but I'll get error as `writeKey` is undefined.

`AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: You must pass your Segment project's write key.`

*sendFunction.test.js*

```
import * as sendFunction from './sendFunction';

test('analytics object should be successfully submitted', async () => {
   let sendAnalyticsSpy;
   sendAnalyticsSpy = jest.spyOn(
     sendFunction,
     'sendAnalytics'
   );
   expect(sendAnalyticsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
```

As what we have is `writeKey` was not exported, just a const variable declared in the class. May I know how can I mock the `writeKey` with Jest?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953365/16068019

Alternatively you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv and create an .env file for your test environment that get's loaded when testing.